# How can i use the relationship between tables to show data in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i build a project about online shop and there is a page in the admin dashboard that show the information about the orders that coming from the users ..there is many tables

- there is **orders** table with **Order.php** class.
- there is **products** table with **Product.php** class.
- there is **orderdetails** table with **OrderDetails.php** class ..in this table there is
  **id**,**order_id**,**product_id**.

every thing is working well put i can't show the $product['name'] and $product['price']
because $orderDet return null value , **I don't know how to catch the id from orderdetails table to use it to get the product table data** .

- the getOne function from class OrderDetails.php

```
//get one
public function getOne($id){
    $query="SELECT * FROM `orderdetails` 
    WHERE  `id` = '".$id."'";
    $result=$this->connect()->query($query);
    $orderdetails=null;
    if($result->num_rows == 1)
    {
        $orderdetails = $result->fetch_assoc();
    }
    return $orderdetails;
}
```

- Orders.php where i show the the customer's information and the orders they buy for the admin

```
<?php 
session_start();

require_once 'classes/product.php';
require_once 'classes/Order.php';
require_once 'classes/Orderdetails.php';
require_once 'classes/Category.php';
require_once 'inc/header.php';

$ord=new Order;
$ordDet=new OrderDetails;
$prod=new Product;
$orders=$ord->getAll();

if(!isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
   header('location:Login.php');
   die();
}

?>

<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
                 <th>Customer Name</th>
                 <th>Customer Email</th>
                 <th>Customer Phone</th>
                 <th>Customer Address</th>
                 <th>Product Name</th>
                 <th>Product Price</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
                     **the problem is here** 
                       <?php
                       foreach($orders as $order)
                       {
                        
                         $orderDetails=$ordDet->getOne($order['order_id']);
                            //var_dump($orderDetails);
                         $product=$prod->getOne($orderDetails['product_id']);
                           
                          
                       ?>
                       
         <tbody>
            <tr>
                 <td scope="row"><?php echo $order['customerName']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $order['customerEmail']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $order['customerPhone']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $order['customerAddress']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $product['name']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $product['price']; ?></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
                        
                      <?php } ?>
                    
        </table>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<?php require_once 'inc/footer.php';?>
```

[that is an image when i make var_dump($orderDetails)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSXiO.png)

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: I will google it

Comment: thank you i will study about that and take it in consider

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```html
$query = "SELECT * FROM `orderdetails` WHERE `id` != ''";
// or $query = "SELECT * FROM `orderdetails` WHERE `id` != 0";
$result = $con->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $id = $row["id"];
    echo "<h3>id is now $id</id>";
}
```

Comment: ```//get one
public function getOne(){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `orderdetails` WHERE `id` != '' ";
$result = $this->connect()->query($query);
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
      
    return ($row);
    
}``` I make it on this way to choose any column i  want in Orders.php when i make var_dump on $row it returns all the rows and when I make var_dump($row['any column ']) it return the data from this column but on the other side when i receive the data from the function in Ordes.php it returns just the first row and show the name and price for the first product in all fields

Comment: now the problem is it just show the first order for each customer, when when the customer buy two products in one order it just show the first product and ignore the second one

Comment: No single credit for giving you my two cents, however, what you need is simple knowledge of Relational Database queries and how to do the queries in php. There are a good number of such tutorials out there.

Answer (score -1):

```html
// The following line is where your problem lies
$query = "SELECT * FROM `orderDetails` WHERE `order_id` != ''";
 /* I assume you know the best way to handle the following part */
$result = $con->query($query);
echo $result[0]["order_id"]; // or $result["order_id]
```

As an advice you need to have a way to select only new orders that you have not processed. You would not want your selection to include orders you have handled each time you want to get new data from the table.

Comment: i will take that in consider ,,when i try to make `order_id`='id'  it make error in the fields when the customer take more than product in the order

Comment: can you please tell me where i suppose to write ```echo $result[0]["order_id"];```           it makes error ```Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\ONLINE_SHOP\classes\OrderDetails.php:24 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ONLINE_SHOP\Orders.php(42): OrderDetails->getOne('39') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ONLINE_SHOP\classes\OrderDetails.php on line 24 ```

Comment: Just loop through the result instead, I was using pdo style, however try sth like var_dump($result); and see what  was returned. for more info about getting the values returned from php query, feel free to google it, there are numerous examples out there and even on this very platform. Here's one https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: ok i reached for this point after lot of search``` public function getOne(){
    $query="SELECT * FROM `orderDetails` WHERE `id` != ''";

    $result=$this->connect()->query($query);
while ($rows =mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    var_dump($rows["id"]);

}```  and var_dump returns ```string(1) "4" string(1) "8" string(1) "9" ...etc``` and want to loop on this value but from all the errors i got clearly it is not array so i can't loop on it....i am a beginner on php so i am sorry if i am not flexible enough

Comment: $rows["id"] is actually a string. each of the $rows returned contains different table columns, and id is just one of the columns, eg $rows["id"], $rows["order_name"],

Comment: So you would loop through $rows not $rows["id"]. $rows is an array but $rows["id"] is a string. Just use a foreach loop as I seen here https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: If things aren't still Ok, just show a screen shop of your table with it's content and all the php and sql code that interact with the table, then I'd write the whole code for you if possible.

Comment: now the problem is it just show the first order for each customer, when when the customer buy two products in one order it just show the first product and ignore the second one